# How can I solve a slow hibernation resumption after moving to a faster drive (SATA to NVME)

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, nvme

#### Context

I have a Windows 7 machine with:

- 32GB ram
- a 6700k processor
- an MSI Z170A Gaming Pro Carbon motherboard
- 1TB Samsung 850 SSD
- 2TB NVME 970 Evo plus (newly installed)

After installing the new 2TB NVME drive, I installed the correct Samsung driver and cloned the 1TB SSD 1-to-1 on it.

Now everything works as expected, except for resuming from hibernation:

When I resume from hibernation it takes about 15-40 minutes.
With the previous 1TB SSD it was maybe 1-2 minutes.

#### Question

How can I solve this slow hibernation resumption?

#### What I've looked into

There is a similar question here: [Windows 7 extremely slow resume from hibernation](https://superuser.com/questions/1341878/windows-7-extremely-slow-resume-from-hibernation)

Unfortunately as a new user I cannot comment on that post or its answers to ask for clarification.

I have Googled for many hours, but found nothing helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! I took the time to format your question such that it is easier to read. Could you take the time and indicate what you've tried so far? Especially: have you tried the suggestions given in the similar question (e.g. the BIOS settings)? Please write down what the result was from the things you've tried, it helps others to come up with a suitable answer.

Comment: Also, out of curiousity: why are you still on Windows 7?

Comment: yes i did and checked everything like in the other thread. Here it needs someone who is a pro and know where the Diffrence between SSD and NVME is and hibernate. Better explained: Need Someone who know that the Bios setting in other thread is a "nice try" but makes technicly no sense in "this" situation. Dont forget: everything else works ;) - And thank YOU very much for clearing the format for better reading!!

Comment: Please edit the question to add what exactly you've tried from the other question and what the outcome was.

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the EnergySettings (deep registry :>) in Windows or in the Samsung NVMe™ Driver (3.3) . Something else makes no Sense. i wrote Samsung, but i wait to get a emailadress... the 0815 support cannot help :). So i will wait. wish me luck or maybe someone here has one idea.

Comment: Maybe!!! this helped: set hiberfil.sys file from basic setting 75% to 100%: powercfg -H -size 100%  .  if you dont hear in two weeks from me, it helped good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: set hiberfil.sys file from basic setting 75% to 100%; start CMD and: "powercfg -H -size 100%" <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I think the driverbug for decompressing the files is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue after I downgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 7. I ran CHKDSK on the boot drive, it ran on the next restart and fixed the issue for me.